# ANGULAR using nativeElement.style: how to change cursor style when click-pressed(click on down state)

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive, angular8

i have native elementRef
CODE:

```
this.eleRef.nativeElement.style = "_____?????_____"
```

what should be in "???" to give **:active** style to element.(i want to change cursor style to change on mouse click down(not click up))

Comment: i dont think it's possible. you should just create a css class and apply that class to your element. also, I recommend you do so using https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Cause the `active` is not part of DOM tree, and because of that do not expose any DOM API that can be used to interact with them.

Usual approach if you want to deal with pseudo-elements programmatically is indirect: you add/remove/change class and in CSS make this class affect the corresponding pseudo-element. So in your case, you could have one more class that changes necessary style:

```
.yourclass:active {/* some styles */}
```

And use the ngClass to add and remove `yourclass`